# Can't activate after reinstalling Windows 11

Tags: linux, windows, windows-11

I messed up a Linux installation process and ended up deleting Windows 11 which was installed on my SSD. I had upgraded from W10, which was installed by the store that built my PC and it was paid for. Is there a way to activate my W11 now?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the same edition of Windows 11? Did the installation ask you to choose what Edition (Home/Pro etc) you want to install? Is there a Licensing Key in Firmware or is there any OEM sticker somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows 10 was activated, so you can reinstall Windows 11 and it will automatically activate. No issue here.

Just install and you will not have any issues.

If activation does not automatically work, call Microsoft Sales Support. The phone number will be in the Windows 11 Systems Settings area.

Microsoft maintains the licensing in their licensing server and it works.

Also ask the Store that built the computer to see if they can rectify the situation.

Comment: Or restore from the disk image you must have made before attempting Linux installation.

Comment: @John I forgot to mention that I've already installed W11 and it didn't get activated. It asked me for a serial key, I went with the 'don't have the serial key now' option, hoping it would be activated by itself. Guess I'll have to contact Microsoft then.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't think I created a disk image before the Linux installation

Comment: Ask the store that built the PC.  I did make a note of this in my answer